# Should I be using Azure AD SAML Toolkit in a production environment?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, saml

I am a bit new to Azure AD and some of its features.  I have a vendor application that wants to setup authentication & single sign on using our Azure Active Directory.  The documentation they provided me with just walks through adding Azure AD SAML Toolkit as the enterprise application and configuring it accordingly.  However, I noticed immediately that the description for that enterprise application was "This is the sample SAML app which customers can use to test the SAML single sign-on integration with Azure AD."

My question is, shouldn't a vendor application have setup an enterprise application for me to add to our Azure tenant or is it common and good practice for applications to use the Azure AD SAML Toolkit for production implementations?

Comment: You can choose Azure AD SAML toolkit to set up SSO enabled in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have found no reason documented that this is bad practice.  We have implemented it for the vendor application and have had no issues up to this point.